# Use Kubernetes and MongoDB Cluster (sharded) on premises

Tags: docker, mongodb

Currently I am investigating the use of Kubernetes together with a MongoDB cluster.

Scenario:
We are planning on creating a sharded Mongo Cluster. We intend to use MongoDB's Ops Manager for the orchestration of the cluster and it's shards. We are planning on dockerizing all the databases (including the Automation Agent) for easier deployment.

Now we are wondering if we could orchestrate the docker images (and VM's) with Kubernetes, but there are multiple challenges:

- We need to ensure that multiple docker containers containing mongo instances of the same shard (replicas) **don't end up on the same machine** as the original. (That would be a replication "fail").
- We are expecting that our databases will grow fairly large (multiple TB in the future, but fairly small right at the beginning), so shouldn't each shard-docker-container get it's own VM at some point? That probably would be something Kubernetes could decide?

There are a lot more challenges I will face and certainly a lot more questions that I should be asking, but these are the most "pressing" ones for me right now.

I also read about Docker Swarm, which seems a lot more simple. So I am wondering if that would be a better alternative.

Are they any pointers/advice you can give me? Am I completely on the wrong track with this?

Links:

- [Docker Clustering Tools](https://technologyconversations.com/2015/11/04/docker-clustering-tools-compared-kubernetes-vs-docker-swarm/)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider that k8s isn't the right place for your Mongo instance to live.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @EEAA. It's also one of the questions I am thinking about.

Comment: @EEAA Do you think that, in general, mongo processes should not be containerised? Or do you mean in this case in particular?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I think that the decision to containerize *any* database process needs to be very carefully considered. This applies to Mongo, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc.

Comment: @EEAA can you elaborate please? As far as I know the performance loss (if that is your concern) through containers should be minimal, since nowadays containers almost directly (or at least very fast) interact with the underlying hardware.

Comment: @skofgar It's not about performance, but rather about reliability. Containers are *great* for orchestrating stateless applications. However IMHO the ecosystem is far too fast-moving, buggy, and unpredictable to entrust it with your database. Databases *must* always be up, and *must* not corrupt data. How sure are you that you can satisfy those two requirements while running inside k8s?